# trouble with geom_smooth execution

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a ggplot with fitted regression lines but they will not show up on the plot. I have consulted the multiple questions/answers on this website that are similar/identical to my own question, but the solutions did not work. Any thoughts on what could be the issue here?

```
    SITEID      SEASON      alpha                NA_L3NAME
1    SB003 2015-Summer 0.90442976     Great
2    SB003 2013-Summer 0.92900730     Great
3    SB003 2016-Summer 0.86553203     Great
4    SB003   1980-Fall 0.95203021     Great
5    SB003 2014-Summer 0.88775522     Great
6    SB014 2013-Summer 0.92816795     Great
7    SB014   1980-Fall 0.95054384     Great
8    SB014   1992-Fall 0.96556002     Great
9    SB014 2011-Spring 0.89072544     Great
10   SB014 1984-Spring 0.89040499     Great
60   SB098   1985-Fall 0.95504602 Plains
61   SB098 1991-Summer 0.94653302 Plains
62   SB098   2013-Fall 0.94871589 Plains
63   SB098 1992-Spring 0.94986767 Plains
64   SB098   2000-Fall 0.93892581 Plains
65   SB098 2012-Spring 0.90170972 Plains
66   SB098   1983-Fall 0.96054060 Plains
67   SB098 1984-Summer 0.9485850 Plains
68   SB098   2015-Fall 0.92830696 Plains
69   SB098 1999-Summer 0.89414055 Plains
70   SB098   1990-Fall 0.95048309 Plains
110  SB105   1994-Fall 0.94860475 Plains
111  SB106   1999-Fall 0.84296516              Hills
112  SB106 1994-Summer 0.93823110              Hills
113  SB106 2011-Summer 0.88867607              Hills
114  SB106   1995-Fall 0.93955643              Hills
115  SB106 2006-Summer 0.93154885              Hills
116  SB106 1996-Spring 0.78595236              Hills
117  SB106 1997-Summer 0.92082755              Hills
118  SB106 2010-Summer 0.92033130              Hills
119  SB106 1985-Summer 0.93490260              Hills
120  SB106   1983-Fall 0.94816017              Hills

PLOT.reprex <- ggplot(reprex_example, aes(x = SEASON, 
                                                     y = alpha, color = reprex_example$NA_L3NAME)) + geom_point(shape = 16, size = 3) + geom_smooth(method = "lm") + theme_bw()+ ylab("Alpha") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 5),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size=10),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size=10),
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            plot.background = element_blank())
    PLOT.reprex
```

Comment: `Season` is a categorical variable in your data sample. It needs to be numeric for `geom_smooth` to work. Maybe convert the seasonal values to quarters of a year (e.g., 1980-Winter = 1980 + 0.25/2). Also, change `reprex_example$NA_L3NAME` to `NA_L3NAME`. The name of the data frame shouldn't be restated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Season is a categorical variable in your data sample. It needs to be numeric for geom_smooth to work. Maybe convert the seasonal values to quarters of a year (e.g., 1980-Winter = 1980 + 0.25/2). Also, change reprex_example$NA_L3NAME to NA_L3NAME. The name of the data frame shouldn't be restated.

The comment above was the correct answer! I have it copied and pasted here.